# c# Оптимальный выбор Micro-ORM

Tags: c#, sql

Мне уже где-то и когда-то давали ответ на даный вопрос и, что довольно странно, я обыскался его и так и не нашел =(

Нашул следующу таблицу сравнений по скорости:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С этим все по ней понятно... Но... 
Кто скажет чем из перечисленного удобнее пользоватся и почему?

Comment: ORM не для скорости, а для удобства. Если вам удобно без него - пользуйтесь sqlreader-ом

Comment: @Monk Он так и спросил "Кто скажет чем удобнее пользоватся и почему?".

Comment: @Andrew: Эээ... И как можно на ваш вопрос дать объективный ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у тебя желание работать со всей БД через ORM и не заморачиваться с запросами, то твой выбор **NHibernate** и **Entity Framework**.

**EF** доступен из коробки, а **NHibernate** нужно качать. Майки обещают, что **EF7** догонит **NHibernate** по производительности.

На сколько я знаю **Linq2Sql** не развивается=> мертв.

При использовании полноценной **ORM**(Коим являются **EF** и **NHibernate**) достигается максимальная удобность и абстракция от низкоуровневого **SQL**-кода, но теряется производительность из-за того, что генерируются неоптимальные запросы.

**Micro-ORM**- это **ORM**, которые не замещают собой работу с **SQL**-запросами, но делают ее удобной. Из-за этого, как ты мог заметить в табличке , Micro-ORM на первых местах.

Если у тебя цель написать свою **ORM**, то для таких целей подойдет **Micro ORM**, например Dapper, который облегчает прямую работу с запросами.

Например, не нужно создавать параметры ручками, а можно пульнуть их во время `EXECUTE` и **Dapper** все сопоставит.

Вообще, выбор **ORM** зависит от конкретных целей и то, что я написал выше, это то, с чем я работал, но на основании этого, можно сделать какие-то выводы.

Comment: "не замещают собой работу с SQL-запросами" - не совсем так. В основном предоставляют C(R)UD, но сверх того могут прятать запросы за LINQ (к примеру linq2db) или билдером запроса (к примеру Dapper.FastCRUD).